# Custom UIVIEW is not showing up? Wrong "override init()"?

Tags: swift, uiview, custom-view

I try to create some kind of a tooltip. But I guess I did something wrong on the init part. Why does my tooltip does not show up in the view? Cant I use the override init like this?

How I init the view:

```
    let test = ToolTipView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x , y: self.view.center.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    self.view.addSubview(test)
```

Here is my custom UIView Class:

```
import UIKit

class ToolTipView: UIView {

    let tipOffset : CGFloat = 10.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        print(frame)

        let mainRect = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: frame.height - tipOffset)
        let roundRectBez = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainRect, cornerRadius: 3.0)
        let mainShape = CAShapeLayer()
        mainShape.path = roundRectBez.cgPath
        mainShape.fillColor = darkGray.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(mainShape)

        let trianglePath = createTip(_frame: frame)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(trianglePath, at: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func createTip(_frame: CGRect) -> CAShapeLayer{
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()

        let tipRect = CGRect(x: _frame.minX, y: _frame.minY, width: _frame.width, height: _frame.height - tipOffset)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: tipRect.midX - 10, y: tipRect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipRect.midX, y: tipRect.maxY + tipOffset))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipRect.midX + 10, y: tipRect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipRect.midX - 10, y: tipRect.maxY))
        path.close()

        shape.path = path.cgPath
        shape.fillColor = darkGray.cgColor

        return shape
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh Ok! Thank you! I ll do some research on frames vs bounds. It looks like I missed this part till now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the *frame* and *bounds* of the view.

The [`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame) of the view is its coordinates within its parent's coordinate system. The [`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds) of the view is its coordinates within its own coordinate system.

When you draw stuff with layers and paths, everything is relative to the view's coordinate system, so you should be using `bounds`, not `frame`. The view's parent is rather irrelevant when you are drawing.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    print(frame)

    // changed all "frame" to "bounds"
    let mainRect = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height - tipOffset)
    let roundRectBez = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: mainRect, cornerRadius: 3.0)
    let mainShape = CAShapeLayer()
    mainShape.path = roundRectBez.cgPath
    mainShape.fillColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(mainShape)

    // here as well
    let trianglePath = createTip(_frame: bounds)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(trianglePath, at: 0)
}
```

Also, when adding the view to its parent, you probably meant to use an x coordinate of 0, or half the width, otherwise the view will exceed its parent's bounds:

```
let test = ToolTipView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: self.view.center.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
// or
let test = ToolTipView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x , y: self.view.center.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, height: 50))
```